# How do I ensure that an event can have zero or multiple sessions?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models, and I have to create a condition between these two models. The condition can be 0 or multiple sessions of an event as follows. How can I do this.

```
class Session(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date=models.DateField()
    end_date=models.DateField()
    speaker=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=100)

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    session=models.ForeignKey(Session,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently your model `Event` is limited to a single `Session`, but of the latter can have multiple of the former model.

You could achieve your wanted condition with a `ForeignKey` on `Session` to `Event`, like:

```py
class Session(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

So if an `Event` exists, it can have no `Session`s, one or multiple.

You can access those with `my_event.session_set.all()`.